# Compile vanitygen source

Tags: vanitygen, open-source

How do I compile this source or get vanitygen for linux?

Open source link:
https://github.com/samr7/vanitygen

Comment: Have you tried simply running `make` in the root directory? If so, what errors did you receive?

Comment: Yes but it gave me 5 source code error such as link 54:14: field 'vxc_bntarg' has incomplete type bigbun

Comment: I managed to fix it on older unintuitive but thx

Comment: Use vanitygen-plus it is still active on GitHub.

Comment: @zhiyan114 Sorry for the late reply. You must either use an older version of Vanitygen. Openssl 1.1 is not supported (use 1.0.something) or apply the patch here: https://github.com/exploitagency/vanitygen-plus/pull/56/files

Answer (score 2):

How to compile:

1. Download the source from Github.
2. Run the ./configure file. (if it doesn't exist, type "./autogen.sh" first.)
3. Type "make".
4. Your program is ready.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you use [Bitaddress.org](https://www.bitaddress.org/)

its open source and secure without the need to install anything.

or you could do that using bitcoin-php library on PHP.

vanitygen is too old and never updated almost since 7 years.

### UPDATE

Sorry for the previous suggestion, I thought bitaddress.org has that function.

`vanitygen` library that you mentioned is too old, you better use 
[vanitygen-plus](https://github.com/exploitagency/vanitygen-plus), it's up-to-date and supports bitcoin and alt-coins.

Comment: These do not perform the same function as vanitygen.

Comment: Yeah, are right, as I remember they had that function. I have edited the answer.